# How to avoid division by zero in UCT formula in Monte Carlo tree search?

Tags: monte-carlo

In step 2 (expansion) of the Monte Carlo tree search algorithm, one or more child nodes are created, and one node named C is chosen among them. The simulation step is applied to C giving it a score of 0/1 or 1/1. What happens to the other newly created leaf nodes? I assume they get a score of 0/0, which will not work very well with the UCT formula that decides which nodes to explore by maximizing wins / total simulations + some other stuff which will cause a division by zero when evaluating this expression. How is this reconciled?

Comment: What is the MCTS algorithm? What is the UCT formula?

Comment: MCTS is the Monte-carlo tree search (popularized by deep mind(?)), and [UCT is Upper Confidence Bounds in Trees](https://www.chessprogramming.org/images/d/d2/Uct-poster-erdmann.png).